# WPF - Go To Line in a TextBox

Tags: wpf, vb.net, winforms, textbox

I'm basically playing around with the WPF TextBox control, recently after swithing from WinForms, and I was just wondering whether there is a way to scroll to a specific line in a WPF TextBox? How can this be achieved?

For WinForms TextBox, Basically, To go to a specific line the code would be something like:

```
Private Sub MoveCaretToLine(txtBox As TextBox, lineNumber As Integer)
    txtBox.HideSelection = False
    txtBox.SelectionStart = txtBox.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(lineNumber - 1)
    txtBox.SelectionLength = txtBox.Lines(lineNumber - 1).Length
    txtBox.ScrollToCaret()
End Sub
```

But I have no idea how I can achieve it for a WPF TextBox? I'm actually hosting a WPF TextBox through HostElement in WinForms and would like to know how I can achieve this.

Comment: If you use FlowDocument you can do Run.BringIntoView but a TextBox will not host a FlowDocument.

Comment: Thank you for that but I'd like to know how I can do this for the WPF TextBox

Comment: Why?  Why not just use another control that does what you need?

Comment: I want to try to use a Wpf textbox because if I was to use another,  it would defeat the purpose of me trying to get the goto feature working on a wpf textbox

Comment: ScrollToCaret is not System.Windows.Controls.TextBox method.  Why are you hosting a WPF TextBox in WinForm?  I wish I could down vote more than once.

Comment: I am in need of the Spellchecker class. The WPF TextBox allows me to do that without any third party classes. The WPF RichTextBox causes poor performance and is the reason why I'm using a WPF TextBox.

Comment: The code above is for Windows Forms TextBox. It shows how I can go to each line using that code. It is not for WPF TextBox. Nothing of that code is a part of WPF TextBox. It was an example. I want to know whether it's possible to go to a line using a WPF TextBox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As is stated  and what you have found there is no ScrollToCaret in WPF, there is a [`ScrollToLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.scrolltoline(v=vs.110).aspx) method and a [`CaretIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.caretindex(v=vs.110).aspx) method, by combining them I think it will work the way you want it to.  See if this works for you

```
 Private Sub MoveCaretToLine(txtBox As TextBox, lineNumber As Integer)
    txtBox.SelectionStart = txtBox.GetCharacterIndexFromLineIndex(lineNumber - 1)
    txtBox.SelectionLength = txtBox.GetLineLength(lineNumber - 1)
    txtBox.CaretIndex = txtBox.SelectionStart
    txtBox.ScrollToLine(lineNumber - 1)
    txtBox.Focus()
End Sub
```